# Calculate Multiple Information Value in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, formula

I am new to R programming and trying to learn part time so apologize for naive coding and questions in advance. I have spent about 1 day trying to figure out code for this and unable to do so hence asking here.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data?select=train.csv

I am working on train Titanic Data set from Kaggle imported as train_data. I have cleaned up all the col and also converted them to factor where needed.

My question is 2 fold:

**1.** Unable to understand why this formula gives IV values as 0 for everything. What have I done wrong?

```
factor_vars <- colnames(train_data) 
all_iv <- data.frame(VARS=factor_vars, IV=numeric(length(factor_vars)),STRENGTH=character(length(factor_vars)),stringsAsFactors = F)
for (factor_var in factor_vars){


all_iv[all_iv$VARS == factor_var, "IV"] <- 
InformationValue::IV(X=train_data[, factor_var], Y=train_data$Survived)


 all_iv[all_iv$VARS == factor_var, "STRENGTH"] <- 
attr(InformationValue::IV(X=train_data[, factor_var], Y=train_data$Survived), "howgood")
}

all_iv <- all_iv[order(-all_iv$IV), ]
```

**2.** I am trying to create my own function to calculate IV values for multiple columns in 1 go so that I do not have to do repetitive task however when I run the following formula I get count of total 0 and total 1 instead of items grouped by like I requested. Again, what is that I am doing wrong in this example?

```
train_data %>% group_by(train_data[[3]]) %>%


summarise(zero = sum(train_data[[2]]==0),
one = sum(train_data[[2]]==1))
```

I get output

```
               zero   one
           
1                   549   342
2                   549   342
3                   549   342
```

where as I would anticipate an answer like:

```
    zero one



 1  80 136



 2  97  87



3 372 119
```

what is wrong with my code?

**3.** Is there any pre built function which can give IV values for all columns? On searching I found iv.mult function but I can not get it to work. Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: (1) Please take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). (2) What do you expect `IV` to be?

Comment: @MartinGal: Thank you for your suggestion on the reproducible example. I have gone through it and next time I will make sure that I try to follow as much as possible however in this case, I wouldn't know how to attach CSV data file.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your questions:

1.

```r
length(factor_vars)
#> [1] 12
```

`length()` returns the number of elements of your vector `factor_vars`. So your code `numeric(length(factor_vars))` is evaluated to `numeric(12)` which returns an numeric vector of length 12, default filled with zeros.

The same applies to `character(length(factor_vars))` which returns a character vector of length 12 filled with empty strings `""`.

2. Your code doesn't use a correct `dplyr` syntax.

```r
library(dplyr)

library(dplyr)

train_data %>% 
  group_by(Pclass) %>%
  summarise(zero = sum(Survived == 0),
            one = sum(Survived == 1))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Pclass  zero   one
   <dbl> <int> <int>
1      1    80   136
2      2    97    87
3      3   372   119
```

which is most likely what you are looking for.

3. Don't know the meaning of `IV`.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and guiding me on my query :) IV means Information Value. I am currently using library(InformationValue) and command IV. However that only lets me assess IV for 1 independent variable at a time and I do not want to type in code for 15 independent variable hence I am trying to find a library / command that would let me create a table of all independent variable against dependant variable in 1 go.